# tex4ht has strange characters at end of section titles when using cprotect

Tags: tex4ht, cprotect

I use `cprotect` package so I can use math in section titles. It works OK in pdf, but tex4ht generates strange characters at end of section title.

If I do not use `cprotect`, then it will not compile in tex4ht.

Is there a way around this? MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\chapter{Listing of integrals}
\cprotect\section{\quad $\int e^x \left(1-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6\right) \, dx$}

stuff

\cprotect\section{\quad $\int \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2+x^2}} \left(2-x^2\right)}{2 x+x^3} \, dx$}
text
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug t.tex "htm,3,mathjax,notoc*,p-width"
```

gives

[image]

If I do not use `\cprotect` then it gives compile error.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(./report.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
[1] [2]
Chapter 1.
(./report.4ct (./report-1.cpt) (./report-2.cpt))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmtt.fd)
! Argument of \im:g has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.9 ...nt e^x \left(1-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6\right) \, dx$}

?
```

**Important**  Please note that the math itself used in section titles in auto-generated by computer algebra system and I did not write the math. A large program runs which read these math equations and use each for section titles. So editing the math is not possible or practical.

TL 2019

Comment: Unrelated there no need for left/right in that header

Comment: the math markup seems sub-optimal but you can remove the `cprotect` package and your example runs without error in pdflatex, so it doesn't seem to be doing anything in recent latex releases. So I would simplify the markup not to use that and then look to get tex4ht to understand if that fails

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, I am not following you when you say I can remove the cprotect package?  tex4ht will give error in that case as I mentioned above. The issue is with tex4ht and not compiling to pdf. Yes, I need a workaround to use math in section titles with tex4ht. I now only know about the cprotect package.

Comment: remove `\cprotect` `\left` and `\right`, then it seems to work OK, and be more correct markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the math itself is autogenerated by CAS systems I am afraid. I did not write the math. A program is run which read the math generated by Maple and Mathematica and uses this math to generate section titles. So I can't edit the math itself. I will add this to the question.

Comment: @Nasser you have been asking here for enough years I'd guess it's CAS generated but CAS generating bad tex isn't really a good starting point, you could fix the generation or locally just define `\left` and `\right` to do nothing.

Comment: why can't your "program which is run" to generate the titles remove `\left` and `\right` it's hard to believe they ever make sense in a section heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but if I change \left and \right to do nothing, it will break other math used elsewhere which is not related to section titles?  OK, I can write code to remove \left and \right just from section titles. But I wanted first to see if there is easier method first.  (ps. I did enter a bug report on this already for tex4ht)

Comment: you can do it locally or simply remove the commands while generating the headings, or put in a bug report for tex4ht to make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original problem is the same as here: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2018q4/002114.html

My solution for this was to create `\fixmathjaxtoc` command, which prevents commands at the moment when they are written to TOC from expansion. It seems this command don't work for `\left` and `\right`, because they fail at the moment they are used in the section. As a workaround, you can disable their expansion completely. As math is handled by MathJax, it doesn't cause any harm:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\def\right{\detokenize{\right}}
\def\left{\detokenize{\left}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I needed to use cprotect somewhere else for verbatim in some titles and section titles and so on. After much debugging, I found just loading the `cprotect` package causes these ^^F^^LL to show up in section header, even if `\left` and `\right` are not there. So I ended up just removing `cprotect` package when using tex4ht only and removed the verbatim stuff from section headers. Now it works. all ^^F are gone. So there is a problem with using cprotect period with tex4ht. So avoiding it all together with tex4ht seems the only way for now.

Comment: @Nasser yes, it seems to be catcode conflicts. I've looked at `cprotect` sources and couldn't understand what's going on, so it is unlikely that I will be able to fix that. Anyway, I think we already tried to fix verbatims in sections in the past, try to search in your mail :) There should be a solution that doesn't need `cprotect`

Comment: No problem, I am trying to change my code to avoid verbatim in titles so I do not have to use cprotect in tex4ht mode. I still need to use it for latex, but I do not load it in tex4ht mode any more. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the markup, removing `\left\right`  then it works in `htlatex` (`cprotect` seems unnecessary here in htlatex or pdflatex)

I get html rendering of

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Listing of integrals}
\section{\quad $\int e^x (1-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6) \, dx$}

stuff

\section{\quad $\int \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2+x^2}} (2-x^2)}{2 x+x^3} \, dx$}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will add code in my program to remove the \left and \right in math just for section\subsection headers  as a workaround until this bug is fixed.

Comment: hi David, I found a conflict with this. i.e. when I followed what you suggested and removed the \eft and \right from math for section header, I found an error in different area due to other issues (when using different font and hyperref). Will post separate question on that now.